# angular bind to a table of select tags - how to get the value?

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I have a table which has a select tag for each table row, and quickly realised i cant use ngModel, at least not in the way you would use it for a single select.

Is there anyway of using angular to bind to each select, and to get the users selected option / values?

thanks

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of owner; let i = index">
<td>{{i + 1}}</td>
<td>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedId" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let brand of brands" [value]="brand.Id">
        {{ brand.name | titlecase }}</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, append index value to ngModel to differentiate each dropdown instead using same ngModel for all dropdowns

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of owner; let i = index">
  <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
  <td>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedId[i]" class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let brand of brands" [value]="brand.Id">
        {{ brand.name | titlecase }}</option
      >
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

code sample - https://codesandbox.io/s/wwnxyjrnr8

Answer (score 0):

Use [selected] attribute like this,

{{ brand.name | titlecase }}

Instead of [ngModel].

Hope this helps